# Determine if running uncompiled .ts script or compiled Deno executable

Tags: deno

I want my program to be able to create a symlink to itself. The problem is that I want to distribute it as a [compiled executable](https://deno.land/manual/tools/compiler), but I also want to be able to test it as a script during development with this functionality still in place. So the trick is, what target should the symlink point to?

If it's a script that should be executed directly (the main file has a [shebang](https://deno.land/manual/examples/hashbang)), then I think that [`Deno.mainModule`](https://deno.land/api?s=Deno.mainModule) would be the ideal target.

If it's a compiled executable, then I think that [`Deno.execPath()`](https://deno.land/api?s=Deno.execPath) would be the ideal target.

The question is, how do I know which is the case? Is there a good way to tell whether or not the program is being run as a compiled executable?

When running an **uncompiled script**, the two values are:

```js
execPath: "/opt/local/bin/deno"
mainModule: "file:///Users/myname/mycode/myprogram.ts"
```

When running a **compiled executable**, the two values are:

```js
execPath: "/Users/myname/mycode/myprogram"
mainModule: "file:///Users/myname/mycode/myprogram.ts"
```

So, the two best heuristics I can come up with to detect if it's a compiled executable are roughly these:

1. detect if `mainModule` and `execPath` are the same (other than the `.ts` extension)

```js
Deno.mainModule === path.toFileUrl(Deno.execPath()) + '.ts'
```

2. detect if the base filename of the `execPath` is not `'deno'`

```js
path.basename(Deno.execPath()) !== 'deno'
```

*Note: I assume that Windows executables will have a `.exe` extension, but I've left that out for simplicity*

I like the first one better because it seems more likely to be invariant, but neither seem quite as invariant as I would hope. Is there a better practice for this? Or am I going about this the wrong way altogether?

Comment: The best way to do this imo is to have a placeholder in your original source code which will be replaced by a variable or an indicator or something when your code is compiled. For example, your source code can include a `const isCompiled = false;` which can be replaced with `const isCompiled = true;` before running `deno compile`, and replaced back with `const isCompiled = false;` after compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not currently an API for discriminating this, but there's an open GitHub issue on the topic if you'd like to follow its status: [denoland/deno#15996 — Runtime API to check whether in self-contained exe](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/15996). There's also a related PR: [denoland/deno#18402 — feat: Add Deno.standalone API](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/18402)

I posted a [comment](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/15996#issuecomment-1265794279) in the original issue describing a workaround, and I'll inline it here as well:

> You can switch on the presence of a specific CLI argument to make the determination, and embed that argument into the compiled binary:
>
> `example.ts`:
>
> ```ts
> import * as path from "https://deno.land/std@0.158.0/path/mod.ts";
>
> const isCompiled = Deno.args.includes("--is_compiled_binary");
>
> const programPath = isCompiled
>   ? Deno.execPath()
>   : path.fromFileUrl(Deno.mainModule);
>
> const programDir = path.dirname(programPath);
>
> console.log({
>   isCompiled,
>   programDir,
>   programPath,
> });
> ```
>
> ```txt
> gh-issue-15996 % deno --version                              
> deno 1.26.0 (release, x86_64-apple-darwin)
> v8 10.7.193.3
> typescript 4.8.3
>
> gh-issue-15996 % deno run --allow-read --no-prompt example.ts
> {
>   isCompiled: false,
>   programDir: "/Users/deno/gh-issue-15996",
>   programPath: "/Users/deno/gh-issue-15996/example.ts"
> }
>
> gh-issue-15996 % mkdir binary_dir
>
> gh-issue-15996 % deno compile --output=binary_dir/example --allow-read --no-prompt example.ts --is_compiled_binary
> Compile file:///Users/deno/gh-issue-15996/example.ts
> Emit binary_dir/example
>
> gh-issue-15996 % ./binary_dir/example 
> {
>   isCompiled: true,
>   programDir: "/Users/deno/gh-issue-15996/binary_dir",
>   programPath: "/Users/deno/gh-issue-15996/binary_dir/example"
> }
> ```
>
> Of course, you'll have to account for this potential extra argument if your program already accepts other arguments — and if you're concerned about the target argument being inadvertently used with the not-compiled script (a false positive), just use something unguessable like a UUID in place of the one I used in the example above.